# How to merge list of videos with frame specifiec order using ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I have a list of files:

```
even_0.avi
odd_0.avi
even_1.avi
odd_1.avi
...
even_n.avi
odd_n.avi
```

And I want to merge them in a single video file in such a way, that zero frame would be taken from `even_0.avi`, first frame from `odd_0.avi`, second - from `even_0.avi` and so on.

And if all frames in `even_0.avi` are taken, then next frame we will take from `even_1.avi`, next from `odd_0.avi`, next again from even_1.avi. Basically, when one video ends, we just start taking frames from the next video with prefix "`even_`" or "`odd_`".

I just started using ffmpeg, know, how to simply merge videos, change resolution, fps and so on, but this is beyond my power, so, please, help.

Comment: why is it tagged c++? Are you going to use the c api of ffmpeg or are you goign to use ffmpeg executable?

Comment: @UmNyobe, any of these. Executable will be great, but C++ with ffmpeg api, if someone will be so kind to write, also great and very intresting.